# How do I retrieve more information about this bulk load error?

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I'm attempting to bulk-load some data into a MySql server, using the `MySqlBulkCopy` class from the [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) library.

For the first table it works just fine.  For the second table, it errors out, saying 0 out of 10 rows were written.  (Using a small data set for testing purposes; real-world usage would involve a lot more rows than that.)

Debugging into the library code, I find that [the warning count](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/blob/master/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs#L58) from the operation's result is 30, and the affected row count is 0, but the library doesn't do anything with those warnings.  They're never surfaced to the user-facing error message, and with the way the reply packet is basically just metadata, I suspect that some additional API call would be needed to retrieve the warnings.

Assuming that I have full access to both the MySql server and the source of the library, what do I have to do to read these warnings and figure out what's going wrong with my bulk load operation?

(Note: Please don't suggest "solving" this by switching to the other MySql ADO.NET driver.  For my use case, that would just be trading one problem for another, potentially worse one.)

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: The following may be helpful regarding `MySqlBulkCopy`: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/780. Perhaps try to use `MySqlBulkLoader` instead.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not asking for help with my code; I'm asking for help with retrieving diagnostic information that a 3rd party library is failing to provide.  The source for it is already available, and linked to inside my question.

Comment: @user9938 Not sure what was different a year ago, but in the current version of the code, `MySqlBulkCopy` is implemented on top of `MySqlBulkLoader`, so it doesn't make much sense to say to use it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches:

#### SHOW WARNINGS

After `MySqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` finishes, call `ExecuteReader` for a `SHOW WARNINGS` command. As per [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-warnings.html) this will "[display] information about the conditions resulting from execution of the most recent nondiagnostic statement in the current session".

#### InfoMessage event handler

Before executing `MySqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer`, attach an event handler to [`MySqlConnection.InfoMessage`](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlconnection/infomessage/). During `WriteToServer`, the event handler will be called with an `MySqlInfoMessageEventArgs` object. This contains an `Errors` property that contains a list of errors and warnings that have occurred.

Comment: Thanks, the event handler was just what I needed.  Turns out the problem was a FK violation, because I made a mistake elsewhere and was inserting things in the wrong order.